# Should I use CString, basic_string<TCHAR>, or something else with ATL/WTL?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, atl, wtl

I've only learned a little bit of ATL in the last couple of days (after realizing how much pain pure Win32 is) and also learned about WTL and MFC, and from what I see, there are quite a few different string classes available for me.

I *used* to do something like this:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
namespace std { typedef basic_string<TCHAR> _tstring; }
```

and then use `_tstring` everywhere in my code. After learning some ATL, I learned that there's a `CString` class in `atltmp.h`. Apparently, there's another `CString` class in WTL, and *yet another* `CString` class in MFC.

I have **no idea** whether I will stick with ATL or whether I'll switch to WTL, MFC, or something else. But right now, I'm in the process of converting my Win32 code to ATL, and I'm not sure what to change and what to keep.

Should I make my strings use `CString` instead of `_tstring`? Is there any benefit in doing so, considering **both** executable size (*excluding* shared libraries) *and* portability/compatibility?

Comment: The only thing you can *legally* add to the `std` namespace is a template specialization. Also, I don't know about WTL, but the CString classes in ATL and MFC are the same, they're both typedefs of CSimpleStringT (I think)

Comment: @Praetorian: Eh, I don't mind engaging in such a non-intrusive illegal activity in a personal project. :P

Comment: I looked up CString on Google the first time I learned about it. NSFW, as it turns out.

Comment: @Toolbox: Oh LOL I'd never tried that (I'd always done `CString class`). Thanks for the warning. XD

Comment: @Praetorian : `CString` in ATL and MFC are indeed the same, however ATL is considered the canonical owner (it's in namespace `ATL` after all...). WTL doesn't have its own that I recall -- I think it just uses ATL's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that I just read is that `CString` does not support null characters.

I guess I'll keep with STL, then.

Answer (score 6):

My preference would be to stick with `CString` for ATL / MFC / WTL. It's not like you have much of an option for portability if you're using those frameworks anyway; and you know what they say: `When in Rome ...`

Also, `CString` does have a few niceties about it

- You can load resource strings from executables using `CString::LoadString`
- Get direct access to the internal string buffer using `CString::GetBuffer/ReleaseBuffer`
- Silently convert between `CStringA` & `CStringW`
- Perform `printf`-like formatting using `CString::Format`

Comment: You can get access to the internal buffer of `basic_string` too -- just do `&str[0]`. But I especially like the 3rd and 4th points -- I think I might drink the cool-aid after all. +1

Comment: Oh, question: Does using `CString` have a noticeable effect on the executable size by any chance? I don't expect that it will, but I don't want to add 100 KiB to an 80-KiB executable just to change string classes.

Comment: If you use statically linked MFC you start out with a 3000 kB, so it doesn't matter that much. :->

Comment: Also, CStrings are referenced counted, making copying cheap. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296565(v=vs.60).aspx#_core_cstring_reference_counting) I have yet to see a std::string that is referenced counted (I don't know it the standard allows this).

Comment: @Andrew Stein C++03 does not forbid reference counted implementations of `std::string`; don't know about C++0x. Also, I remember reading somewhere that libstdc++ does implement reference counting for `std::string`

Comment: @Andrew: OK then I'll definitely use CString, reference counting is something I've always wanted. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Praetorian: I turns out that my version of ATL (2.1, from the Windows 2003 DDK) doesn't have any method to *remove* characters. Guess I'll stick with `basic_string` then...

Comment: @Mehrdad So all the member functions Remove, Mid, Left, Right are missing?

Comment: @Praetorian: Oh whoops, my bad. I was looking more for things like `Substring`, `Remove`, etc... those definitely exist, but I totally missed them. Thanks!

Comment: @Prætorian *silently* convert? I always thought you had to use the macros `CT2W`, etc.